# Group the data by semesters in HTML and CSS viewer in Power BI

Tags: html, css, powerbi, dax

I need your help.

I downloaded HTML & CSS viewer in Power BI Desktop and I try to write a DAX code in it.
I can write a code for semesters and for courses separately but I could not put the courses according to their semesters to show what courses a student have passed in concrete semester.
I could reach only this visual at this moment using these formulas below:

Course Name
    "& CONCATENATEX(DISTINCT('Courses'[Semester ID ]), "  "& 'Courses'[Semester ID ],,'Courses'[Semester ID ],ASC)&"
    "&CONCATENATEX(FILTER('Courses','Courses'[Semester ID ]='Courses'[Semester ID ]),"   "& 'Courses'[Course Name ] &" ","",'Courses'[Semester ID ],ASC) &"
  
 
![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DQQH.png)

I want to achieve this result instead of visual I created above:

[image]

This is working example file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ufv1gLffwnK2KQXoh9imoh3e5z7knP8J/view?usp=sharing
so, I need semester id 38 in group (when subject is several).
Thank you so much in advance,

also, I tried this formula:
CONCATENATEX(SUMMARIZE('Courses', 'Courses'[Semester ID ],'Courses'[Course Name ]), "   " & Courses[Semester ID ] & "  "&  'Courses'[Course Name ] &"  ")